# What's being used to check code coverage in Django?

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage

Django doesn't appear to have built in support for code coverage. Is therea defacto-standard tool for checking it in Django 1.3?

Comment: Nothing to do with Django, this is a Python question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ned Batchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14343/ned-batchelder)'s [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) is the authoritative tool for test coverage in python.